# PhoneGap confirm callback function

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova

I'm currently working on a mobile application using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap 2.0.0.
The app is an html file with different div elements that represents the screens of the app and a native container is used to display the screens using javascript code.

For several actions, I have been using the native alert and confirm functions to interact with the user.
For example:

```
function customBeforeMenuItemClick(screen, menuItem) {

if (screen === "APPROVALQUEUE" && menuItem === "Close") {
    return (confirm('Do you want to close without submitting changes?'));
}
}
```

Here the function takes the return from the confirm popup and uses it in an other function (over which I have no control) to process the action of closing or not the app.

Now I need to modify the title of the popups and thought of using the Phonegap functions navigator.notification.alert and confirm. However, these functions are asynchronous and the execution of the script continues.

I have tried to use the callback method to return the correct boolean but the function using the confirm popup has alreday finished executing

```
function onConfirmClose(button){
return (button == 1);
}

function toClose(){
navigator.notification.confirm("Close?", onConfirmClose,
 'Do you want to close', 'yes,no'); 
}

function customBeforeMenuItemClick(screen, menuItem) {

if (screen === "Start" && menuItem === "Cancel") {
    toClose();
}
else {return true;}
}
```

In this example code, the popup flashes briefly before disappearing when the app is closed after function toClose() has finished.

I have tried using the callback function to set a global variable that would be used to return the result of the popup but it didn't work.

Is there a way to get the result of the navigation.notification.confirm  ?

Comment: what's in `button` when it comes in `onConfirmClose`?

Comment: button is the index of the button pressed on the notification.confirm (ie 1 for 'yes', 2 for 'no').
Here is the documentation from Cordova's website http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

Comment: yes I know that, but *in your code*, does it get there? what does it have? it's always easier to put in evidence what exactly doesn't work

Comment: Well, this function is used to close the app so usually I don't event have time to press the button and it is not set.
When I cancel the call to close the app and leave it the time to get to this partt of the code, the "button" does contains 1.

Comment: ok so that the problem is in `onConfirmClose`, I posted you the answer, try this out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may close the app like this:

```
// you may alert the callback button to make sure which button sends which index
var YES_BUTTON = 1; // assuming that the 'YES' button will send the index 1

function onConfirmClose(button){
    // alert(button); ?
    if (button == YES_BUTTON) {
        navigator.app.exitApp(); // close the app
    }
}
```

If that still fails, you may take a look at the [API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.confirm_full_example) then start from the example for your test.

Comment: I have tried such an approach but the thing is, the call to the confirm is within the function closing the app (it's how Sybase unwired platform implements it). So the closing function continues its execution and finishes before I can get the result of the confirm action.
Since every function is called after a specific event, I will try to modify somehow my app as a workaround.

Comment: @Khalid please post all the relevant code so we can know what exactly the question is